# Save input field data to Localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, storage

*I am new here, so please forgive me if I am in the wrong place.*

I started to use JavaScript a couple of weeks ago.

I would like to save a name in the local storage with an input field, then query this name again on a second page. The goal is that a user writes the name, etc. on page one and then comes with a button on page two where all entries are listed for printing. Page two is still missing.

With my code, I unfortunately can't get any further and I don't get anything saved.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Bitte Eintragen</legend>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name Eingeben">
    <button type="button" id="eingabeknopf">Speichern</button>
    <button type="button" id="löschen">Löschen</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Ausgabe</legend>
    <div id="lsAusgabe"></div>
</fieldset>

<script>

   const name = document.getElementbyId("name") 
   const eingabeknopf = document.getElementbyId("eingabeknopf") 
   const lsAusgabe = document.getElementbyId("lsAusgabe") 
   const löschen = document.getElementbyId("löschen")   


   eingabeknopf.onklick = function () {

       const name = name.value;

       console.log(name);

       if name {
           localStorage.setItem(name);
           location.reload;
       }
   };

   for (let i= 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
       const name = localStorage.name(i);

       lsAusgabe.innerHTML += `${key}: <br />`;
   }

   eingabeknopf.onklick = function() {
       localStorage.clear();
   }

</script>
```

Comment: First off, you have several syntax errors.  You need to wrap `name` in `()` with the if statement so `if (name) {...}`.  It's also `getElementById` with a capital "B".

Comment: Always check the error console.

Comment: Additionally `onklick` is called `onclick` and `location.reload` is missing `()`

Comment: with the `setItem` method to need to set the key and the value [Storage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

Comment: okay i try it :) thx for the fast help !